# Trying to make grep a variable

Tags: variables, grep

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please type the file name"
read filename
echo "Please type the word or phrase you wish to look for"
read string
grep '$string' /home/pi/$filename
```

I was wondering how I could make grep a variable so I could use a code like this:

```
if [ $var=~$string ];
then
echo "the string is there
else 
echo "sorry string doesn't exist"
```

Comment: I solved these problems in the past by saving the result of `grep` once it has been piped to `wc -l` to count occurences. If it is greater than 1, I know it exists.

Comment: shouldn't it be greater than 0?

Comment: @mfaerevaag: Yep, wasn't paying attention when I wrote that :)

Answer (score 1):

To assign the output of grep to a variable:

```
var = $(grep '$string' /home/pi/$filename)
```

**EDIT**

As @staticx pointed out, in your case, where you grep for `$string` and see if the result again matches `$string`, it would be easier just to see if grep finds the element by piping it `wc -l`.

```
count = $(grep '$string' /home/pi/$filename | wc -l)
if [ count -gt 0 ]; then
    # do stuff
fi
```

Comment: and if it occurs multiple times? piping it to wc -l would probably be better

Comment: your absolutely correct. didn't read the question too carefuly. updated the answer :)